# Pause FFMPEG and resume it with newest frame

Tags: ffmpeg

For my software, I use FFMPEG to write frames from a tcp video stream into a bitmap file.

I need to pause and resume the FFMPEG process, which I accomplish with sending SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to the process.

However, when FFMPEG is resumed, it seems to continue with the frame it left off. Instead, I would like FFMPEG to write the newest frame seen by the camera into the bitmap file.

Does somebody know how to achieve that?

I looked into the documentation of FFMPEG and found the switch -vsync, but do not really understand the effect of "passthrough", "vfr" or "drop". Can someone please explain with an example what these arguments do?